# What is the remainder when 50^51^52 divided by 11?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> To find the remainder:

$$50^{51^{52}} \mod 11$$

I have solved till:

$$6^{51^{52}} \mod 11$$

But not able to proceed further. Help please.

Comment: Do you mean:  $50^{51^{52}}$?

Comment: By little Fermat you should firsct compute $51^{52}\bmod {10}$

Comment: The remainders of $6^N\pmod{11}$ repeat in a cycle.  Once you know that cycle, as Hagen says, look at powers of 51 to find out where you will be in that cycle.

Comment: do you mean $50^{\{51^{52}\}}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Euler's theorem. $50^{51^{52}}$  is going to be congruent to $50^a$ if $a$ and $51^{52}$ are congruent $\bmod \varphi (11)=10$. So we only need to calculate the last digit of $51^{52}$, which is $1$. Therefore $50^{51^{52}}\equiv 50^1\equiv 6 \bmod 11$

Answer (score 1):

$a^{b}\bmod{c}=a^{(b\bmod{\phi(c)})}\bmod{c}$

Therefore:

$50^{51^{52}}\bmod{11}=50^{(\color\red{51^{52}\bmod{\phi(11)}})}\bmod{11}=50^{(\color\red{51^{52}\bmod{10}})}\bmod{11}=50^{\color\red{1}}\bmod{11}=6$